# Whats the gain of this op amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain, non-inverting

what i did here is take current over the 4.7 kilo ohm and since there are no other voltage input other than the one then shouldn't the Vout be 0.2127 volts? thats not possible for a non-inverting amplifier right? do i just assume Vin = Vout in this case then?

[image]

Comment: Where is that schematic from? I've got a few words for the author of that – If they are using the battery symbol where they actually mean a voltage source, they should at least realize that this symbol is polarized.

Comment: No, that calculation is totally wrong. How did you end up with 0.2127 V? Can you explain? Because, then we can help you understand your misunderstanding

Comment: i took the voltage over the 4.7 volt resistor so then i got 0.2127 mA and then i also considered the 1 kilo resistor and the current shouldn't have dissipated anywhere as so i thought it would be the same current over the 1k resistor getting  0.2127 volts, which is parallel to Vout?

Comment: Why do you think that any current is flowing in the 4.7k resistor? What is the input impedance of an ideal opamp?

Comment: i just assumed since we also have a Vin of 1 volt. Does that mean that Vin= Vout then?

Comment: Input currents are ~10 pA to 1uA  (FET to BJT) so yes Vo=Vi as always for non-inverting unity gain

Comment: @HaidyE yes, Vout = Vin+, but not because "magic" or "that's the default" or something, but because 1. no current flows into the inputs of an ideal opamp and 2. the ideal opamp has a very high amplification. From these two simple rules and very little math actually follows that the Opamp adjusts the output to be like Vin+.

Comment: yeah! thank you all so much for the help. I get it now, i was just doubtful and confused :D

Answer (score 0):

That's just a unity gain amplifier. So gain=1, Vout=Vin. The 4.7k resistor doesn't matter, unless you get close to (or beyond) the supply voltages.